How to handle null dates in fact table?
I have a date table dimension.
This links to the sales fact table on date -> delivery_date
The date table is created using DAX. The sales fact table is pulled from a table in the OLTP db.
Some rows in the sales table have delivery_date as null.
How to model such a scenario?

That's a business/domai question - we can't really help you with that.

...also, why are you asking "how to model such a scenario" when the database tables already exist? That means the data modelling was already completed ages ago.

The tables are in the OLTP database. I'm pulling it into Power BI and created the dimension and fact table.
